# JQuery : Display the list of Files selected and remove the ones before uploading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, upload

I am using a multi-file upload with a form in django. I want to diplay the selected files in a list and that the user is able to remove the files that he wants before uploading. There is a delet button for it.

I based on a post to do on Jquery. It works to display the files, and remove them from the list that is diplayed on the webpage. However the files that are removed are still uploaded even if the are not display in the list.

Thank you

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('id_Filename');
var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('fileselect');

var fileList = [];
var renderFileList, sendFile;

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(evnt) {
  fileList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
    fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
  }
  renderFileList();
});

renderFileList = function() {
  fileListDisplay.innerHTML = '';
  fileList.forEach(function(file, index) {
    var fileDisplayEl = document.createElement('p');
    fileDisplayEl.innerHTML = `${file.name} <button data-index="${index}" class='deletfile'>X</button>`;
    fileListDisplay.appendChild(fileDisplayEl);
  });
};


$(document).on('click', '.deletfile', function() {
  const index = $(this).attr('data-index');
  fileList.splice(parseInt(index, 10), 1);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>

<div> 
  <input type="file" name="Filename" class="form-control" multiple="" onchange="javascript:updateList()" maxlength="255" id="id_Filename"> 
</div>

<div class="block-file-selection">
  <p>Selected files:</p>
  <div id="fileselect"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You **can not** manipulate the selection the user makes in a file input field, via JavaScript. If you want a functionality like this - then you can't submit the form normally; you need to use JavaScript to build the request containing only the files you want to upload, and use AJAX/fetch to send it.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure that I understood it well. We can not use django to generate the input files form to do that. It has to be done by Javascript and Ajax. There is no way to do it by with a Django backend ?

Comment: The backend can't do anything about this at all, because this is a client-side problem. You could switch to not using the `multiple` attribute, and instead add/remove file upload fields to upload _one_ file each - that would be a bit easier to handle, because you'd only need to remove these fields from the form again (or disable them), if you want a particular file not to upload. But it will be less comfortable for the user, because they won't be able to select multiple files at once any more, but would have to pick each one individually.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Doy you have a quick solution to impliment with this html ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're directly tagging me, as I've not had any input on this question. @CBroe's advice is entirely correct though.